# javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01843: not a valid month

Tags: java, oracle, jsp

I tried to insert some values in Oracle database but when i try to insert Date format in database its giving me ja**vax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01843: not a valid month** i google it but still issue is not resolve Here is my code, in table column datatype is DATE

```
    Date date2=new Date();
           String strdateformat="hh:mm:ss";
           DateFormat dateformat=new SimpleDateFormat(strdateformat);
           String formattime=dateformat.format(date2);

 Date date5=new Date();
 SimpleDateFormat mysimpledateformat=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mmm-yyyy");
            String mydatestring=mysimpledateformat.format(date5);
 String TIME_OUT_HISTORY="";
              punch_out_timespamp=null;
        timeelpased=null;

 PreparedStatement ps=con1.prepareStatement("insert into EMPLOYEE_LOGIN_TIME(EMPLOYEE_ID,TIME_IN,TIME_OUT,WORKING_HOUR,PUNCH_DATE,TIME_OUT_HISTORY) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)");
           ps.setString(1, Employee_id);
            ps.setString(2,formattime);
            ps.setTimestamp(3, punch_out_timespamp);
            ps.setObject(4, timeelpased);
            ps.setString(5,mydatestring);
            ps.setString(6,TIME_OUT_HISTORY);
            ps.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: What is the data type of the `TIME_IN` column? What are you passing as the `formattime` parameter?

Comment: TIME_IN is timestamp for this i written this code  Date date2=new Date();
           String strdateformat="hh:mm:ss";
           DateFormat dateformat=new SimpleDateFormat(strdateformat);
           String formattime=dateformat.format(date2);

Comment: That is where your error is. You are passing a time as a String in `hh:mm:ss` format to a `TIMESTAMP`  that is expecting years, months, days as well as hours, minutes and seconds.

Comment: @MT0 : i updated my whole code earlier it was work fine i putted datatype as varchar but since i change datatype of TIME_IN,TIME_OUT as TIMESTAMP(6) WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE and PUNCH_DATE as DATE i stucked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[TL;DR]** Use the correct data types in your prepared statement parameters.

- If the column is a `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` data type then pass the values using `ps.setTimestamp( int, java.sql.Timestamp )`.
- If the column is `DATE` and you want the time component to always be midnight then use `ps.setDate( int, java.sql.Date )`.
- If the column is a `CHAR` or `VARCHAR2` then use `ps.setString( int, String )` - do not use this for dates/timestamps.

---

Why convert it to a string and then back to a date? Just use the date in your prepared statement.

Also, if `TIME_IN` is a date or timestamp data type then you should be passing the value as a `java.sql.Timestamp` value not as a string (and relying on Oracle to implicitly convert the value - which may be what is failing).

```
PreparedStatement ps=con1.prepareStatement(
  "insert into EMPLOYEE_LOGIN_TIME("
    + "EMPLOYEE_ID, TIME_IN, TIME_OUT, WORKING_HOUR, PUNCH_DATE, TIME_OUT_HISTORY"
   + ") values(?,?,?,?,?,?)"
);
ps.setString(    1, Employee_id );
// ps.setString(    2, formattime );
ps.setTimestamp( 2, new java.sql.Timestamp( System.currentTimeMillis() ) );
ps.setTimestamp( 3, punch_out_timespamp ); // Should this be punch_out_timestamp?
ps.setObject(    4, timeelpased );         // Should this be timeelapsed?
ps.setDate(      5, new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis()) );
// Java 8
// ps.setDate(      5, java.sql.Date.valueOf(java.time.LocalDate.now()));
ps.setString(    6, TIME_OUT_HISTORY );
ps.executeUpdate();
```

or even - do not pass it to the query as a parameter:

```
PreparedStatement ps=con1.prepareStatement(
  "insert into EMPLOYEE_LOGIN_TIME("
    + "EMPLOYEE_ID, TIME_IN, TIME_OUT, WORKING_HOUR, PUNCH_DATE, TIME_OUT_HISTORY"
   + ") values(?,SYSTIMESTAMP,?,?,TRUNC( SYSDATE ),?)"
);
```

---

**Update**:

> `TIME_IN` is timestamp for this i written this code
>
> ```
> Date date2=new Date();
> String strdateformat="hh:mm:ss";
> DateFormat dateformat=new SimpleDateFormat(strdateformat);
> String formattime=dateformat.format(date2);
> ```

This is why your error is occurring (and a good reason to post the complete code when you ask a question!).

You are passing a `hh:mm:ss` string to a `TIMESTAMP` column and Oracle will implicitly try to convert the string to a `TIMESTAMP` using the `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` session parameter (which is probably something like `DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF6`) and when it does not match that format then it will throw an exception.

Do not convert it to a string and back - just use:

```
ps.setTimestamp( 2, java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(java.time.LocalDateTime.now()) );
```

or

```
ps.setTimestamp( 2, new java.sql.Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()) );
```

or remove the bind parameter and use

```
SYSTIMESTAMP
```

in the `INSERT` statement.

Comment: punch_out_timespamp and timeelpased   is blank value TIME_OUT=punch_out_timespamp  and WORKING_HOUR=timeelpased  , i change code but still facing same error here i change code Date date5=new Date();
           DateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat(("dd-mmm-YYYY"));
           String format_date_punch=sdf.format(date5);

Comment: @Aties There is nothing in this answer that converts a string to a date - you should not get that exception. Please edit your question with a [MCVE] including the full (relevant) code (i.e. declarations of the variables you use and input values) and the full error message.

Comment: @Aties Updated.

Comment: Brother its working fine but time is inserted this format : 12-APR-18 05.22.02.189000000 PM is possible to inserted date as HH:MM:SS ?

Comment: @Aties No - a `TIMESTAMP` always has year, month, day, hour, minute, second and fractional seconds (and is stored as 20 bytes - without any format). If you just want the time component then use `TO_CHAR( time_in, 'HH24:MI:SS' )` in your select statement when you query the column.

Comment: ok bro thank you really thank you for your help :) god bless you :)

Answer (score 1):

Change `DD-mmm-YYYY` to `dd-MM-yyyy`

Comment: still facing  java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01843: not a valid month error

Comment: Debug the value of `format_date_punch` and make sure it meet the oracle `to_date` standard